# Particle Js Canvas overflow in other div

Tags: javascript, css, particles.js

I am using a Particle Js Canvas in my site. but the problem is it overflows in my other div .
as shown Below :
[image]

Is there any way I can hide it. the problem is that the canvas captures th efull sceen as its background but i want to show it only on paricular div and Hide from others.

THank You

Answer (score -2):

Use `overflow: hidden;` in your JS Canvas div's parent.

Imagine you have this structure:

```
<div class="ParentDiv">
        <div class="MyJSCanvas"></div>
</div>
```

Just add this:

```
.ParentDiv { overflow: hidden; }
```